# Mixing Kafka Streams DSL with Processor API to get offset

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to find a way to log the offset when an exception occurs.

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
void createTopology(StreamsBuilder builder) {
 builder.stream(topic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), new JsonSerde()))
        .filter(...)
        .mapValues(value -> {
          Map<String, Object> output;
          try {
            output = decode(value.get("data"));
          } catch (DecodingException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
            // TODO: LOG OFFSET FOR FAILED DECODE HERE
            return new ArrayList<>();
          }
          ...
          return output;
        })
        .filter((k, v) -> !(v instanceof List && ((List<?>) v).isEmpty()))
        .to(sink_topic);
}
```

I found this: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#streams-developer-guide-dsl-transformations-stateful
and it is in my understanding that I need to use the Processor API but still haven't found a solution for my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ValueTransfomer` can also access the offset via the `ProcessorContext` passed via `init`, and I believe it's much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution, as suggested by IUSR: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73465691/14945779 (thank you):

```
static class InjectOffsetTransformer implements ValueTransformer<JsonObject, JsonObject> {

  private ProcessorContext context;

  @Override
  public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
    this.context = context;
  }

  @Override
  public JsonObject transform(JsonObject value) {
    value.addProperty("offset", context.offset());
    return value;
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {
  }

}
```

```
void createTopology(StreamsBuilder builder) {
 builder.stream(topic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), new JsonSerde()))
        .filter(...)
        .transformValues(InjectOffsetTransformer::new)
        .mapValues(value -> {
          Map<String, Object> output;
          try {
            output = decode(value.get("data"));
          } catch (DecodingException e) {
            LOGGER.warn(String.format("Error reading from topic %s. Last read offset %s:", topic, lastReadOffset), e);
            return new ArrayList<>();
          }
          lastReadOffset = value.get("offset").getAsLong();
          return output;
        })
        .filter((k, v) -> !(v instanceof List && ((List<?>) v).isEmpty()))
        .to(sink_topic);
}
```